# TestContainers - Is it possible to run containers manually before starting tests?

Tags: testcontainers

Using `docker-compose.yml` and `DockerComposeContainer` I managed to start the whole stack and run my tests. (To make it faster, I implemented a singleton instance of `DockerComposeContainer`). This is fast enough when I run all tests together.
But in the middle of development, often, I run one single test. In this case getting  the whole stack up and down is expensive.
My question is, is it possible to get the whole stack up (using `docker-compose up` command) and keep developing and running tests? If not, is it possible to add such feature? (I'm willing to work on the feature, though I'm totally new to the library). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a [PR](https://github.com/testcontainers/testcontainers-java/pull/1781) under development.